# Passing data between two UIViewControllers using Swift and Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I was using below code to selected UITableView to pass data between UIViewControllers

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

How to do same thing using swift with tableView selected data?

I have tried below approach for simple passing which is working

but How to replicate above mentioned case.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController

    detailsVC.passedString = "hello"

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showRecipeDetail" {

            var detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            detailsVC.passedString = recipes![indexPath?row]
            //or try that if above doesn't work: detailsVC.passedString = recipes[indexPath?row]
        }
    }
}
```

This line could require amendments:

```
destViewController?.destViewController.recipeName = recipes![i]
```

it depends is you properties optional or not (maybe you have to remove ? or !)

Comment: if let i = ip?.row {
            let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? RecipeDetailViewController
            destViewController?.destViewController.recipeName = recipes![i]
        } - can you explain what you are doing here

Comment: let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        detailsVC.passedString = players[indexPath?.row] - can't i directly write this code

Answer (score 0):

Try this... If you're first view controller is embedded inside Navigation Controller, you can push the second view controller on didSelectRowAtINdexPath delegate, as below...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Create a storyboard instance.....
    var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    // Create a SecondViewController instance, from the storyboardID of the same.
    var seconVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("seconViewControllerID") as SecondViewController
    seconVC.passedString = receipes[indexPath.row] as String
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
}
```