# Send label text data with segue in TableView in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

Good evening.

I have here in Swift a TableView that lists some items. I want to, when the user click on it, show a new ViewController with details about that item (like name, photo, desc.) So, here is my tableView funcs:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listExample.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellExample", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExampleTableViewCell

    //Remove separators margins
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero

    cell.labelExample.text = listExample[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

I've done some research and found that maybe I can do that with that function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

But, how can I send the selected item (the label in this case) to the new viewController where I'll have an other label for title, for example?

Comment: You can use a storyboard segue from your dynamic prototype cell to the destination view controller, instead of programmatically calling `performSegueWithIdentifier`.  Less code for you to write and maintain makes it easier to update your app as new versions of iOS are released.

Comment: @PetahChristian hi! sorry for late. so, I can make the text pass thru a view to another one just with storyboard? without coding?

Comment: Absolutely.  Here is [a question which answers how to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420772/passing-data-between-two-uiviewcontrollers-using-swift-and-storyboard) via a storyboard segue.  It uses `prepareForSegue` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked it that example! @PetahChristian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally done that using this example: [Passing data between two UIViewControllers using Swift and Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420772/passing-data-between-two-uiviewcontrollers-using-swift-and-storyboard)

It's make a lot easier and helps me finally get it to work!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this in this function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let text = listExample[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(yourSegueIdentifier, sender: text)
}
```

And you override this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == yourIdentifierAbove {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! YourControllerType
        let textPass = sender as! String

        controller.variableWillReceive = textPass
    }

}
```

Comment: `sender` shouldn't misused as the object to be passed to the destination view controller.  `sender` is understood and expected to be the object that triggers the segue.  Apple's documentation even describes it as "The object that you want to use to initiate the segue."

Comment: @PetahChristian yes, in this case he want text so it is text.

Comment: sender is *not* what is being sent -- the text.  sender should be the object that triggered the segue -- the cell --  in the same manner that a button would be the sender of a touch up event.  You would get the selected cell's text in `prepareForSegue` (since it generally would be a storyboard segue) instead of passing it in to the function.  That's a proper design pattern.

Comment: So what is problem here. Object I want is the text, in destination it need, so I pass it.

Comment: The code is not readable or understandable, since `sender` means "object doing the sending," not "object being sent." The problem is "code smell."  You can ask about this on [codereview.se](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you want a better explanation of the problem.

Comment: Hi @vienvu thanks for the help and sorry to be late. I tried your code but when I click at list item the app crash with this log: Could not cast value of type 'App_Test.ExampleTableViewCell' (0x100091720) to 'NSString' (0x19f351798).

Comment: @RodrigoSchneiderWernke self.performSegueWithIdentifier(yourSegueIdentifier, sender: text) if sender you set is cell, it will uncast to nsstring. If you put in sender string you want you will not meet this error.

Comment: I've done exactly the same as your example and it's saying that. let varTest = listExample[indexPath.row]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailExampleSegue", sender: varTest)

Comment: @RodrigoSchneiderWernke check my demo : https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoPassDataTableVIew

Answer (score 2):

First create a segue from your View Controller with the Table View in it to the second View Controller. Give the segue an identifier, such as "detailViewSegue".

You have the right idea with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Add a line to it so it looks like this (with the corresponding segue identifier):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailViewSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Finally override the function prepareForSegue. You will need a class variable in your second View Controller to pass the data to. In this example `dataToPass` in the first View Controller is passed to `dataPassed` in the second.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "detailViewSegue") {
        //replace SecondViewController with the name of your second view controller
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

        vc.dataPassed = self.dataToPass
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to elaborate?

Comment: Don't need, just keep your idea :)

Comment: Ok. But in my case, dataToPass would be? Sorry, I tried with somethings here and only warnings.

Comment: dataToPass is the data you want to pass to the second View Controller. So in your case it might be an Item object that has the parameters you want like name, photo, or description. When you assign that object to the variable dataPased in the second View Controller it becomes available to use in that second VC.